# Is there a continuous surjection from the closed unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R ^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Is there a continuous surjection from the closed unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R ^2$?

If yes, please give examples. I'm a little stuck on this. What if I replace the closed unit square with the  open one?

Comment: For the second part, do you know an answer for an open interval and the real line?

Comment: Please make the body of your question self-contained. The title is important, but should be separate from the body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The continuous images of unit square are compact so they are bounded in plane.

Comment: If they replace the closed unit square with the open one, it is possible however (using some form of tangent function).

Comment: I get the argument for the closed square. But what about the open case?

Comment: @user173185 It is a basic fact in topology that a continuous image of a compact set is compact.  The unit square is compact, the plane is not, therefore the plane is never the continuous image of the square.

Comment: @you-sir the *closed* unit square is compact. The open unit square is in fact homeomorphic to the plane (hint: $\tan$).

Answer (score 1):

For the open case: take  $f(x,y)=(\ln(-\ln x),\ln(-\ln y))$.